# Importance of stability in optimal control

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

This is a quite general question, so even answers highlighting particular papers or books will be very helpful.

Given an optimal control problem of the form
$$\min_{u\in\mathbb{R}^k} Loss(x,u) \;\;s.t. \;\; \dot{x}(t) = f(t,x,u),$$

when is the stability under small perturbation in the initial data of the plant equation $\dot{x}(t) = f(t,x,u)$ relevant? In these cases, why is it relevant?

For simplicity let us consider a Bolza problem, so $Loss(x,u) = f_u(\Phi^T(x_0))$, where $\Phi^T$ is the flow of the ODE at time $T>0$.

I am quite new to control problems, so I know the importance of stability for dynamical systems in general and even the various available notions, but I don't get why for control problems it should be important.

Comment: When you mean initial data, do you mean the initial condition (initial state $x_0$)? Just to confirm that that is what is being perturbed. Or is it a parameter of the model $f$ like a $\varepsilon$ perturbation of inertia or other parameter within the model.

Comment: Yes, Sorry. I mean initial condition, so to start with $x_0$ and $x_0+\eta$ where $\|\eta\|<\varepsilon$, and are how their difference evolves in time.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question... You ask why robustness is important? In reality you don't know the initial conditions exactly (you might have an estimate). So even if a controller is optimal for one specfic x0
this is not enough. If the controlled system gets already unstable for a small perturbation the controller is useless in practice.

Comment: @SampleTime Yes, I mean robustness to changes in initial conditions. Your comment slightly clarifies my ideas, so when you talk about stability to small perturbations, you refer to the stability of the linearized model about a generic trajectory? Is it exponential stability? Because I am wondering if Lyapunov stability of the solutions is necessary to be required or if it is "too much". Thank you

Comment: @Dadeslam I think you mix up different things here. I did not refer to stability of a linearized model but of the nonlinear system. I don't understand the following parts. "Is it exponential stability" - what are you refering to? And what do you mean with "too much"? Too much of what/for what? Note that Lyapunov stability is not the same as exponential stability (exp. stability is stronger). Also you usually always want at least Lyapunov stability because otherwise the solutions are not bounded and this means you wont be minimizing your Loss function.

Comment: @SampleTime Ok thanks for the fact about Lyapunov functions, so to check robustness to initial conditions, what would be the check you do?

Comment: @Dadeslam I didn't mention Lyapunov functions in my comment. You might be able to check robustness to initial conditions with the help of a Lyapunov function though. But this applies quite generally and is not specific to optimal control.